# find modified and new added columns list from particular table In sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to find modified and new added columns list from particular table In SQL Server 2008 ?

I am working with database and need to know list of tables which are modified.

Comment: Do you mean new columns added to the database or columns that have had data contained within them modified?

Comment: Can you compare the existing database against a "baseline" version? Should be pretty simple to find the differences in columns, e.g. using a tool like Red-Gate SQL Compare, or even just querying the `sys.columns` system catalog view.

Answer (score 2):

You can get modified and created columns by querying sql server metadata views:

```
 SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(sc.[object_id]) as [table]
    ,sc.[name] as [column]
    ,so.modify_date
    ,so.create_date
  FROM [sys].[columns] sc
  JOIN [sys].[objects] so
  ON sc.[object_id] = so.[object_id]
  ORDER BY so.modify_date DESC, so.create_date ASC
```

Comment: I found it useful to include the schema name `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(sc.[object_id])` and ignore items in the `sys` schema